# Ldap error doesn't redirect to file

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, ldap, error-handling

I'm running a loop querying ldap server for a single dn every time, just to see if it's running okay. I want to output both the successful and unsuccessful responses to a file and while the former works, the latter just gets dumped on a screen and I can't figure out why. This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 20000); do
    ldapsearch -x -LLL -D "cn=manager,ou=ft,o=cudb,c=es" -w normal -h 10.22.127.4 -p 389 -b 'dc=IMSI, ou=identities,ou=ft,o=cudb,c=es'
done | while IFS= read -r line; do echo "[---- PL0 ----] $(date) $line"; done >> search_imsi_$(date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S').log 2>&1
```

I've also tried to pipe the output in the loop (not after done) and error still get's printed on screen. The error in question is:

```
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

The return value of this error is 255.

Is this some special kind of error that doesn't get redirected like the usual ones, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message from ldapsearch is being [printed to the stderr stream](http://www.openldap.org/devel/gitweb.cgi?p=openldap.git;a=blob;f=clients/tools/ldapsearch.c#l1855), which is not being caught before the `| while`.

If you had been trying to redirect it with just a `>`, that would explain why it wasn't working inside the loop.

If you want to capture ldapsearch's error output, change your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 20000); do
    ldapsearch -x -LLL -D "cn=manager,ou=ft,o=cudb,c=es" \
      -w normal -h 10.22.127.4 -p 389 \
      -b 'dc=IMSI, ou=identities,ou=ft,o=cudb,c=es' 2>&1    ## <-- added "2>&1" here
done | while IFS= read -r line
do 
  echo "[---- PL0 ----] $(date) $line";  
done >> search_imsi_$(date '+%Y_%m_%d__%H_%M_%S').log      ## no need for 2>&1 here
```

I reformatted the script a little to make it easier to see the loops and the two changes. Since the second loop is only running an `echo` statement (to stdout), there's no need to redirect stderr there.